# How to only print the text of a tweet using Tweepy ? ( Python 3 )

Tags: python, tweepy

I wrote this code in Python 3 using Tweepy, here's what I got:

## Code:

```py
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("secret :)", "secret :)")
auth.set_access_token("secret :)", "secret :)")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

status = api.search(q="Chuck Norris", count=1)
print (status)
text = status.text
print (text)
```

## Output

```json
C:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/main.py
[Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x03718970>, _json={'created_at': 'Fri Feb 26 14:15:04 +0000 2021', 'id': 1365304377318211586, 'id_str': '1365304377318211586', 'text': '"Chuck Norris can kill a Shaolin Grandmaster with an Icecream."\n\n#KingBibi #BlaBla', 'truncated': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [{'text': 'KingBibi', 'indices': [65, 74]}, {'text': 'BlaBla', 'indices': [75, 82]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': []}, 'metadata': {'iso_language_code': 'en', 'result_type': 'recent'}, 'source': '<a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Test Test R2</a>', 'in_reply_to_status_id': None, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'user': {'id': 1203673488, 'id_str': '1203673488', 'name': 'Ariel Pinco', 'screen_name': 'ArielPinco', 'location': '', 'description': 'אולי יום יבוא ויהיה פה טוב.', 'url': None, 'entities': {'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': 15, 'friends_count': 95, 'listed_count': 0, 'created_at': 'Thu Feb 21 09:35:16 +0000 2013', 'favourites_count': 4580, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': False, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': 26104, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_background_image_url': 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_image_url_https': 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'has_extended_profile': False, 'default_profile': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none'}, 'geo': None, 'coordinates': None, 'place': None, 'contributors': None, 'is_quote_status': False, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 0, 'favorited': False, 'retweeted': False, 'lang': 'en'}, created_at=datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 26, 14, 15, 4), id=1365304377318211586, id_str='1365304377318211586', text='"Chuck Norris can kill a Shaolin Grandmaster with an Icecream."\n\n#KingBibi #BlaBla', truncated=False, entities={'hashtags': [{'text': 'KingBibi', 'indices': [65, 74]}, {'text': 'BlaBla', 'indices': [75, 82]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': []}, metadata={'iso_language_code': 'en', 'result_type': 'recent'}, source='Test Test R2', source_url='http://example.com/', in_reply_to_status_id=None, in_reply_to_status_id_str=None, in_reply_to_user_id=None, in_reply_to_user_id_str=None, in_reply_to_screen_name=None, author=User(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x03718970>, _json={'id': 1203673488, 'id_str': '1203673488', 'name': 'Ariel Pinco', 'screen_name': 'ArielPinco', 'location': '', 'description': 'אולי יום יבוא ויהיה פה טוב.', 'url': None, 'entities': {'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': 15, 'friends_count': 95, 'listed_count': 0, 'created_at': 'Thu Feb 21 09:35:16 +0000 2013', 'favourites_count': 4580, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': False, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': 26104, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_background_image_url': 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_image_url_https': 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'has_extended_profile': False, 'default_profile': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none'}, id=1203673488, id_str='1203673488', name='Ariel Pinco', screen_name='ArielPinco', location='', description='אולי יום יבוא ויהיה פה טוב.', url=None, entities={'description': {'urls': []}}, protected=False, followers_count=15, friends_count=95, listed_count=0, created_at=datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 21, 9, 35, 16), favourites_count=4580, utc_offset=None, time_zone=None, geo_enabled=False, verified=False, statuses_count=26104, lang=None, contributors_enabled=False, is_translator=False, is_translation_enabled=False, profile_background_color='C0DEED', profile_background_image_url='http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profile_background_image_url_https='https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profile_background_tile=False, profile_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', profile_image_url_https='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', profile_link_color='1DA1F2', profile_sidebar_border_color='C0DEED', profile_sidebar_fill_color='DDEEF6', profile_text_color='333333', profile_use_background_image=True, has_extended_profile=False, default_profile=True, default_profile_image=False, following=False, follow_request_sent=False, notifications=False, translator_type='none'), user=User(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x03718970>, _json={'id': 1203673488, 'id_str': '1203673488', 'name': 'Ariel Pinco', 'screen_name': 'ArielPinco', 'location': '', 'description': 'אולי יום יבוא ויהיה פה טוב.', 'url': None, 'entities': {'description': {'urls': []}}, 'protected': False, 'followers_count': 15, 'friends_count': 95, 'listed_count': 0, 'created_at': 'Thu Feb 21 09:35:16 +0000 2013', 'favourites_count': 4580, 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': False, 'verified': False, 'statuses_count': 26104, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False, 'profile_background_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_background_image_url': 'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_image_url_https': 'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', 'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'has_extended_profile': False, 'default_profile': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': False, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'notifications': False, 'translator_type': 'none'}, id=1203673488, id_str='1203673488', name='Ariel Pinco', screen_name='ArielPinco', location='', description='אולי יום יבוא ויהיה פה טוב.', url=None, entities={'description': {'urls': []}}, protected=False, followers_count=15, friends_count=95, listed_count=0, created_at=datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 21, 9, 35, 16), favourites_count=4580, utc_offset=None, time_zone=None, geo_enabled=False, verified=False, statuses_count=26104, lang=None, contributors_enabled=False, is_translator=False, is_translation_enabled=False, profile_background_color='C0DEED', profile_background_image_url='http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profile_background_image_url_https='https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profile_background_tile=False, profile_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', profile_image_url_https='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1109543296316116997/3ZL6mr0j_normal.jpg', profile_link_color='1DA1F2', profile_sidebar_border_color='C0DEED', profile_sidebar_fill_color='DDEEF6', profile_text_color='333333', profile_use_background_image=True, has_extended_profile=False, default_profile=True, default_profile_image=False, following=False, follow_request_sent=False, notifications=False, translator_type='none'), geo=None, coordinates=None, place=None, contributors=None, is_quote_status=False, retweet_count=0, favorite_count=0, favorited=False, retweeted=False, lang='en')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    text = status.text
AttributeError: 'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'text'
```

You can see that there's plenty of information there, but I only want to have the tweet's text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting the error traceback in your question, you do not need to the *entire* traceback, only the relevant parts are necessary. It would also be much appreciated if the question were formatted so that code, traceback, and other text can all be distinguished from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's learn how to read documentation:

1. [Search the internet](https://www.google.com/?q=tweepy+documentation) for Tweepy documentation -> https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/
2. Look up the search method you want to use -> https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#search-methods
3. It says 'Return type: `SearchResults` object. Find what that object is -> https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.10.0/search.html?q=SearchResults
4. Turns out the documentation for this is missing -> **consider using something other than Tweepy.**
5. You can now go check the Tweepy source or try to read the error... let's try the error
6. `'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'text'` means that the var you call `status` is actually of the type `SearchResults`. When you've printed it looked like a list, so let's check if it behaves like one:

```
results = api.search(q="Chuck Norris", count=1)
print(results[0])
# Output: Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API ...)
```

7. So we can do `status = results[0]`
8. Looking at the error, we see that the new `status` is now of type `Status` and from the error it is likely to have the fields mentioned in the representation (`_api`, `_json`, `id`, `created_at`, `text`, `entities`, `author` ...)
9. Wait! `text`! Thats what we want!

```py
api = tweepy.API(auth)
results = api.search(q="Chuck Norris", count=1)
status = results[0]
text = status.text
print(text)
# Output:
# "Chuck Norris can kill a Shaolin Grandmaster with an Icecream."
# 
# #KingBibi #BlaBla
```

Comment: Thanks ! I really feel stupid right now, I'm french and I'm young so yeah sometimes I don't really understand what peoples says in the documentation, I'll try my best to understand next time, thanks !

Comment: No worries, we all started out somehow :) Also, the documentation for Tweepy isn't the greatest as demonstrated. With Python, the error messages are usually quite helpful. The best thing you can do is read them carefully and use command such as `type`, `dir` (and sometimes even `help`) in the interactive console (IDLE or even better ipython) to explore what each objects are and what they are capable of. Also, if the answer here helped, don't forget to mark it as accepted.